# Spring Boot Authorization Server send request to external service to get user details

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authorization, microservices

I got a lot of services and I want to centralize my authentication with an authentication-service. Now I am a noobie at Spring boot and I have no clue how do I make this possible.

I just implement the normal security from Spring and it works perfectly and I only find some tutorials about `jdbcAuthentication`, `inMemoryAuthentication`, etc but not an authentication where the authentication-service send a request to another service. Does anyone get a clue about this?

My security based on tokens -> `JWT`

I think I need to manipulate the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` because it decides whether a username is valid or not.

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
}
```

and I make my request with Feign - maybe the wrong location for this code

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    AccountCredentials credentials = new ObjectMapper()
            .readValue(req.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);

    UserRequest userRequest = Feign.builder()
            .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
            .target(UserRequest.class,"http://localhost:7998/api/user-service/user/" + credentials.getUsername());

    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(),credentials.getPassword(),emptyList()));
}
```

Comment: The idea behind JWT is that they're stateless and self-contained.

Comment: Yes but to get a token you need to verify username and password. And these data doesn't belong to my auth-service. He should always ask my user-service. After that, he returning the token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure it this way:

```
@Override
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
    auth.userDetailsService(getUserDetailsService());
}

@Bean
UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
  return username ->
  {
    JSONObject user = callUserService(username); //Here you send the UserRequest
    if(user.has("email")) {
       return new User(
         user.getString("email"),
         user.getString("password"),
         true, true, true, true,
         Collections.emptyList());
     } else {
          throw new BadCredentialsException("BadCredentialsException");
      }
    };
 }
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to get the request data type? Because it will send via request body and I need for my API Request the body username.

Maybe as a parameter? 

PS: It works with your approach just I need the request.

Comment: I think you need to provide an example of what you need. Also, if this answer works for you please mark it as correct.

Comment: I don't know how but the username got already the username from the request body :D Can you explain it to me?

return username ->
  {

Comment: I think that's what `Spring` does automatically. It takes the username you send to the authorization service and use it to call the function that `getUserDetailsService` returns.

Comment: How to get the userame and password from the controller to userDetailsService? So that we can pass the username and password to the external API.